# Adam optimizer in Keras works when using FP32 but not FP16, why?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I noticed that when training a sequential model in Keras using FP16, `mse` as loss function and `adam` as optimizer; the loss can't be calculated and I get a `nan` value.

There is no issue when using FP32, or changing the optimizer with FP16 (I tried both adamax and sgd). Am I missing something or is there something wrong with the implementation of `adam`?

A code snippet is available [here](https://gist.github.com/husmen/8c9ef0eef2cfb6b5621b51f143e60b09)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try setting epsilon to a bigger value:

keras.backend.set_epsilon(1e-4)

Default epsilon might be too small for fp16 calculations.

Comment: yeah, that was the problem, I forgot to update with the answer after finding it.